# Function that iterates through list to create different objects

Tags: r

I currently have written a function where I am individually going through a number of twitter handles and names an object depending on that twitter user's last name. For example:

```
f <- function() {
  dougjones <- rtweet::get_timeline('@SenDougJones', n = 50, max_id = NULL, home = FALSE, parse = TRUE, check = FALSE, token = token, include_rts = FALSE)
  bennet <- rtweet::get_timeline('@SenatorBennet', n = 50, max_id = NULL, home = FALSE, parse = TRUE, check = FALSE, token = token, include_rts = FALSE)
  blumenthal <- rtweet::get_timeline('@SenBlumenthal', n = 50, max_id = NULL, home = FALSE, parse = TRUE, check = FALSE, token = token, include_rts = FALSE)
}
```

I want to simplify this by creating a list of user last names and of their twitter handles to create some code that would look like this (if the code worked correctly)

```
list <- list(
  handles(handle = 
  tibble(c('@SenDougJones','@SenatorBennet','@SenBlumenthal')),
  names(name = tibble(c('Jones','Bennet','Blumenthal')))

f <- function(list){
  for(i in seq_along(list$handles)){
  for(j in seq_along(list$names)){
   names[[j]] <- rtweet::get_timelines(list$handles[[i]],n=50,max_id=NULL,home=FALSE,parse=TRUE, check = FALSE, token = token,include_rts=FALSE) }}}
```

I know this code is wrong because I get NULL when I run it. I was wondering how would I go about doing this. Essentially what I am hoping to do is to feed through the twitter handles iteratively through the get_timeline() function and to also name the objects from each iteration based on the last name of the user.

I am somewhat new with using loops so I have no clue if this is a syntax issue or what, but I was hoping you all might have suggestions. What should I do to get this outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what exactly you are looking for, but the following should do the trick.

```
last.names <- c('Jones','Bennet','Blumenthal')
twitter.handles <- c('@SenDougJones','@SenatorBennet','@SenBlumenthal')

my.list <- list(last.names = last.names,
                twitter.handles = twitter.handles,
                indexes = seq_along(last.names))

my.list$twitter.timeline <- lapply(my.list$indexes,
       FUN = function(index) {
         print(paste(my.list$last.names[[index]], my.list$twitter.handles[[index]], sep = ";"))
         
         twitter.timeline <- rtweet::get_timelines(my.list$twitter.handles[[index]],
                                                                   n=50,
                                                                    max_id=NULL,
                                                                    home=FALSE,
                                                                    parse=TRUE,
                                                                    check = FALSE,
                                                                    token = token,
                                                                    include_rts=FALSE)

           return(twitter.timeline)
       })
```

HTH!

Comment: It looks like this is doing what I would want it to: I am recieving the following error running this code: Error during wrapup: more elements supplied than there are to replace
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart

Comment: I have updated the code in my answer. Please have a look. The error was raised because I tried to replace one element (an integer, the sequence) with multiple elements (which is what get_timelines returns).